# Jasmine in windows command-line

Tags: windows, maven, command-line, jasmine

How to run jasmine from command-line using a Windows machine ? I have seen jasmine scripts run in Linux. I want jasmine standalone in command-line without phantomjs or any other javascript code that mocks the server(I need jasmine only, if possible with maven).

Comment: Yes Alexei, I am looking for executing a javascript testing framework like Jasmine in windows command-line.

Comment: Jasmine probably can run with CScript... you'll need at least have ome wrapper script that will load (main code + your tests + Jasmine ) and than trigger the tests... Also I'm kind of surprised why you would want to avoid any tools that are not on the box by default (even PhantmoJS does not require any setup and can run Jasmine tests immediately).

Comment: I doubt if I can club jasmine with CScript. That is not the question here. I want to know if I can run jasmine via command line in windows with all its set up files intact, let alone running javascript in windows and the like.

Answer (score 1):

I'm lost... Assuming the question is "can I run JavaScript on default Windows install, can I run tests with Jasmine this way"?

CScript/WScript will run JavaScript, both a part of default Windows install (I believe starting W2K or WinXP).

You can also compile JavaScript with .Net compiler (JSC.exe) again available on most machines (.Net is not default on WinXP - so may not be present, Windows Vista/7/8 come with a version .Net by default).

Note that JavaScript by itself has nothing to do with browser and both above tools are not going to provide you any support for browser objects. You can run logic code/manipulate files and configuration, output text.

There is some chance that Jasmine can be run from command line without browser objects - try yourself if you goal is running non-browser related JavaScript from Windows command prompt.

There is also option to automate IE and run script there (again default IE may not be latest version - but Windows 8 comes with IE 10 - should be enough for most browser related tests). You should be able to write your own automation framework (similar to Selenium) if needed, even using JavaScript...

Sample JavaScript to run with `CScript /nologo launchIE.js` from command prompt:

```
// save as launchIE.js 
WScript.Echo("Launching IE to Bing"); // outputs text to console
var oIE = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application.1");
oIE.Visible=1;
oIE.Navigate("http://www.bing.com");
```